# How to write native 64 code in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am using Visual C++ 2012 to write an win32 application running on Windows 7 X64.

from sizeof (long), I get the value is 4.

In Macos x64, long is now 8.

I am wondering how to write native x64 program using Visual C++ 2012 or 2010?

Comment: Did you try adding an x64 platform to your project?

Comment: `sizeof(long)` will be 4 even in a 64 bit build in Visual Studio. Try `sizeof(void*)` as a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

64-bit Windows sticks with 4-byte longs. See this table: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

MS succinctly lays out how to target 64-bit platforms in VS 2012 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s(v=vs.110).aspx